# How to find duplicate sets of values in column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a database table in SQL Server like this:

```
  +----+--------+
  | ID | Number |
  +----+--------+
  |  1 |      4 |
  |  2 |      2 |
  |  3 |      6 |
  |  4 |      5 |
  |  5 |      3 |
  |  6 |      2 |
  |  7 |      6 |
  |  8 |      4 |
  |  9 |      5 |
  | 10 |      1 |
  | 11 |      6 |
  | 12 |      4 |
  | 13 |      2 |
  | 14 |      6 |
  +----+--------+
```

I want to get all values ​​of rows that are the same with last row or last 2 rows or last 3 rows or .... in column Number, and when finding those values, will go on to get the values ​​that appear next and count the number its appearance.

Result output like this:

1. If the same with the last row:

- We see that the number next to 6 in column Number is 4 and 5.
- Times appear in column Number of pair 6,4 is 2 and pair 6,5 is 1.

  ```
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | "Condition to find" | "Next Number in column" | Times appear |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   |                   6 |                       5 |            1 |
   |                   6 |                       4 |            2 |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
  ```

2. If the same with the last two rows:

   ```
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | "Condition to find" | "Next Number in column" | Times appear |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | 2,6                 |                       5 |            1 |
   | 2,6                 |                       4 |            1 |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   ```
3. If the same with the last 3 rows:

   ```
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | "Condition to find" | "Next Number in column" | Times appear |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | 4,2,6               |                       5 |            1 |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   ```
4. And if the last 4,5,6...rows, find until Times appear returns 0

   ```
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | "Condition to find" | "Next Number in column" | Times appear |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   | 6,4,2,6             |                         |              |
   +---------------------+-------------------------+--------------+
   ```

Any idea how to get this. Thank so much!

Comment: What's the SQL Server version?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer which uses the 'Lead' function - which (once ordered) takes a value from a certain number of rows ahead.

It converts your table with 1 number, to also include the next 3 numbers on each row.

Then you can join on those columns to get numbers etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #Src (Id int PRIMARY KEY, Num int)
INSERT INTO #Src (Id, Num) VALUES
  ( 1, 4),
  ( 2, 2),
  ( 3, 6),
  ( 4, 5),
  ( 5, 3),
  ( 6, 2),
  ( 7, 6),
  ( 8, 4),
  ( 9, 5),
  (10, 1),
  (11, 6),
  (12, 4),
  (13, 2),
  (14, 6)

CREATE TABLE #SrcWithNext (Id int PRIMARY KEY, Num int, Next1 int, Next2 int, Next3 int)

-- First step - use LEAD to get the next 1, 2, 3 values

INSERT INTO #SrcWithNext (Id, Num, Next1, Next2, Next3)
SELECT      ID, Num, 
            LEAD(Num, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Next1,
            LEAD(Num, 2, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Next2,
            LEAD(Num, 3, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS Next3
    FROM    #Src

SELECT * FROM #SrcWithNext

/* Find number with each combination */

-- 2 chars
SELECT  A.Num, A.Next1, COUNT(*) AS Num_Instances
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Num, Next1 FROM #SrcWithNext) AS A
        INNER JOIN #SrcWithNext AS B ON A.Num = B.Num AND A.Next1 = B.Next1
WHERE   A.Num <= B.Num
GROUP BY A.Num, A.Next1
ORDER BY A.Num, A.Next1

-- 3 chars
SELECT  A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2, COUNT(*) AS Num_Instances
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Num, Next1, Next2 FROM #SrcWithNext) AS A
        INNER JOIN #SrcWithNext AS B 
            ON A.Num = B.Num 
            AND A.Next1 = B.Next1 
            AND A.Next2 = B.Next2
WHERE   A.Num <= B.Num
GROUP BY A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2
ORDER BY A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2

-- 4 chars
SELECT  A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2, A.Next3, COUNT(*) AS Num_Instances
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Num, Next1, Next2, Next3 FROM #SrcWithNext) AS A
        INNER JOIN #SrcWithNext AS B 
            ON A.Num = B.Num 
            AND A.Next1 = B.Next1 
            AND A.Next2 = B.Next2
            AND A.Next3 = B.Next3
WHERE   A.Num <= B.Num
GROUP BY A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2, A.Next3
ORDER BY A.Num, A.Next1, A.Next2, A.Next3
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef918394b03f172565eb39f28786d7fd) to check.

Notes

- The A.Num <= B.Num means it finds all matches to itself, and then only counts others once
- This answer finds all combinations. To filter, it currently would need to filter as separate columns e.g., instead of `2,6`, you'd filter on `Num = 2 AND Next1 = 6`. Feel free to then do various text/string concatenation functions to create references for your preferred search/filter approach.

Comment: thank you very much! It returns roughly what I need, but is there a shorter way?

Comment: There probably is, but I have tried to keep it simple because I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the function (e.g., are you only ever asking for one combination? Or are you cascading questions e.g., find the most common value, then with that, find the most common pair of values etc). As such, there is some work for you to do. Hence the 'keep it simple' approach.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking that you want to create the "pattern to find" as a string.  Unfortunately, `string_agg()` is not a windowing function, but you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, p.*
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(number, ',') within group (order by id) as pattern
      from (select top (3) t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.id <= t.id
            order by t2.id desc
           ) t2
     ) p;
```

You would change the "3" to whatever number of rows that you want.

Then you can use this to identify the rows where the patterns are matched and aggregate:

```
with tp as (
       select t.*, p.*
       from t cross apply
            (select string_agg(number, ',') within group (order by id) as pattern
             from (select top (3) t2.*
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id <= t.id
                   order by t2.id desc
                  ) t2
            ) p
       )
select pattern_to_find, next_number, count(*)
from (select tp.*,
             first_value(pattern) over (order by id desc) as pattern_to_find,
             lead(number) over (order by id) as next_number
      from tp
     ) tp
where pattern = pattern_to_find
group by pattern_to_find, next_number;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b424ef0045006519ed9de69d4d096da0) is a db<>fiddle.

If you are using an older version of SQL Server -- one that doesn't support `string_agg()` -- you can calculate the `pattern` using `lag()`:

```
with tp as (
       select t.*,
              concat(lag(number, 2) over (order by id), ',',
                     lag(number, 1) over (order by id), ',',
                     number
                    ) as pattern
       from t
      )
```

Actually, if you have a large amount of data, it would be interesting to know which is faster -- the `apply` version or the `lag()` version.  I suspect that `lag()` might be faster.

EDIT:

In unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can get the pattern using:

```
select t.*, p.*
from t cross apply
     (select (select cast(number as varchar(255)) + ','
              from (select top (3) t2.*
                    from t t2
                    where t2.id <= t.id
                    order by t2.id desc
                   ) t2
              order by t2.id desc
              for xml path ('')
             ) as pattern
     ) p
```

You can use similar logic for `lead()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This is exactly what I was expecting but I get this error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.". May be my version of SQL Server doesn't support!.

Comment: @SBPAE .  . It is not clear to me how those features are being used in this query.  As the SQL Fiddle shows, this code works.  And the window functions used in this answer are in all supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @SBPAE . . . The window functions are available in *all* supported versions of SQL Server.  You should be using a supported version.

Comment: When i use the apply version, i get this "'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name", and with the lag() version, i get "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.".

Comment: Yes, i'm downloading a new SQL version!

Comment: When i use your query for unsupported versions of SQL Server, the result return false, it only returns the result for the first n rows in TOP(n) of the table

Comment: @SBPAE . . . It needs the `order by` twice in the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem by converting "Number" column to a string.
Here is my code using a function with input of "number of last selected rows":
(Be careful that the name of the main table is "test" )

```
      create function duplicate(@nlast int)
            returns @temp table (RowNumbers varchar(20), Number varchar(1))
            as 
            begin
                
    
    declare @num varchar(20)
                set @num=''
                declare @count int=1
                while @count <= (select count(id) from test)
                begin
                  set @num =  @num + cast((select Number from test where @count=ID) as varchar(20)) 
                  set @count=@count+1
                    end
                    declare @lastnum varchar(20)
                    set @lastnum= (select RIGHT(@num,@nlast))
                    declare @count2 int=1
                    while @count2 <= len(@num)-@nlast
                    begin
                          if (SUBSTRING(@num,@count2,@nlast) = @lastnum)
                            begin
                              insert into @temp
                              select @lastnum ,SUBSTRING(@num,@count2+@nlast,1)
                          end 
                  set @count2=@count2+1
                end
            return
        end 
go 
select RowNumbers AS "Condition to find",  Number AS "Next Number in column" , COUNT(Number) AS "Times appear" from dbo.duplicate(2) 
group by Number, RowNumbers
```